# Pygame program not executing properly

Tags: python, pygame, execution

When i run this pygame program, a window is supposed to pop up, but nothing happens. Am i doing something wrong?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
```

Comment: maybe program ends and it closes window. Do you get any error message ? Did you try to add at least `time.sleep(1)` or use endless loop `while True` ? Or maybe on some systems it will not open window if you don't use `pygame.events.get()`. What system do you use Window/Mac/Linux ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the program ends and closes the window. You should create some sort of game loop to keep the window open. An easy fix is to use an infinite `while` loop after the last line.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

while True:
    pass
```